# protractor GET and PUT API call

Tags: api, xmlhttprequest, protractor

I want to do API call in my protractor test case inside beforeAll() function and once I get the promise return my Test cases should start running. as my test cases are heavily dependent on API response.
I tried using jQuery however it is showing 'jQuery is undefined.' I am using protractor5.3.0.

```
var data ={
    "request": {
        "urlPattern": "/portal/user/profile",
        "method": "GET",
        "headers": {
            "Accept": {
                "contains": "application/json"
            },
            "Content-Type": {
                "contains": "application/json"
            }
        }
    },
    "response": {
        "bodyFileName": "abc.json",
        "headers": {
            "Content-Type": "application/json",
            "Access-Control-Allow-Headers": "Content-Type",
            "Access-Control-Allow-Credentials": "true",
            "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "{{request.headers.Origin}}"
        },
        "transformers": [
            "response-template"
        ]
    }
};

function setUserProfile(profile, data){
    var id;
    if(data) {
        data.response.bodyFileName = "abc.json";
    }
    jQuery.ajax({
        url: "someurl",
        type: 'GET',
        dataType: 'json',
        contentType:  'application/json',
        success: function(result) {

            result.mappings.forEach(function(mappingItem) {
                if(mappingItem.request.urlPattern === '/portal/user/profile') {
                    id = mappingItem.id;
                }
            });
            jQuery.ajax({
                url: "someurl",
                type: 'PUT',
                data: JSON.stringify(data),
                dataType: 'json',
                contentType:  'application/json',
                success: function(result) {
                    console.log("success?", result);
                }
            });
        }
    });
}

describe('Logout Page', function () {
    var userDropdownEle;
    beforeAll(function () {

        request('someurl', function (error, response, body) {
            console.log('error:', error); // Print the error if one occurred
            console.log('statusCode:', response && response.statusCode); // Print the response status code if a response was received
            console.log('body:', body); // Print the HTML for the Google homepage.
        });

        userDropdownEle = element(by.css(logoutSelectors.dropDownButton));
        xchangePageObject.getLoginUrl();
    });
});
```

Comment: It is easy to send HTTP requests using NodeJS native HTTPS/HTTP module or `got` library. There are many libraries which have the capability to do it.

Comment: there is very less documentation with https/http module, do u have any example which has been implemented with protractor

Comment: There is plenty of documentation on http module.  https://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_http_request_options_callback